# Fractals explained

Tags: php, fractals, mandelbrot

For a while now I've been interested in fractals, the math behind them and the visuals they can produce.

I just can't really figure out how to map the mathematical formula to a piece of code that draws the picture.
Given this formula for the mandelbrot set: `Pc(z) = z * z + c`
How does that compare to the following code:

```
$outer_adder = ($MaxIm - $MinIm) / $Lines;
$inner_adder = ($MaxRe - $MinRe) / $Cols;
for($Im = $MinIm; $Im <= $MaxIm; $Im += $outer_adder)
{
  $x=0;
  for($Re = $MinRe; $Re <= $MaxRe; $Re += $inner_adder)
  {
    $zr = $Re;
    $zi = $Im;
    for($n = 0; $n < $MaxIter; ++$n)
    {
      $a = $zr * $zr;
      $b = $zi * $zi;
      if($a + $b > 2) break;
      $zi = 2 * $zr * $zi + $Im;
      $zr = $a - $b + $Re;
    }
    $n = ($n >= $MaxIter ? $MaxIter - 1 : $n);
    ImageFilledRectangle($img, $x, $y, $x, $y, $c[$n]);
    ++$x;
  }
  ++$y;
}
```

Code is not complete, just showing the main iteration part for brevity.

So the question is: could someone explain to me how the math compares to the code?

Edit: To be clear, I've found dozens of resources explaining the math, and dozens of resources showing code, but nowhere can I find a good explanation of the two combined.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disclaimer. I didn't know anything about fractals before, but always wanted to know, so I've read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) and decided to write what I've found here.
As they say, if you want to understand something, try explaining it to someone else. ;)

Okay, we're going to operate on complex numbers. A complex number is actually a pair of (real) numbers, so, for us php programmers, let it be a two-elements array.

```
    /// Construct a complex number from two reals
    function cpl($re, $im) {
        return array($re, $im);
    }
```

Now we need to tell php how to do arithmetics on our complex numbers. We'll need addition, multiplication and the mod ("norm") operator. (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/ComplexNumbers.html for more details).

```
    /// Add two complex numbers.
    function cadd($p, $q) {
        return cpl(
            $p[0] + $q[0],
            $p[1] + $q[1]);
    }

    /// Multiply two complex numbers.
    function cmul($p, $q) {
        return cpl(
            $p[0] * $q[0] - $p[1] * $q[1],
            $p[0] * $q[1] + $p[1] * $q[0]);
    }

    /// Return the norm of the complex number.
    function cmod($p) {
        return sqrt($p[0] * $p[0] + $p[1] * $p[1]);
    }
```

Now we write a function that returns true if the given (complex) point $c belongs to the mandelbrot set

A point `c` belongs to the set if all points `z = z^2 + c` lie inside the circle with the radius 2.

- We start with the complex number z = (0, 0).
- On each step we calculate z = z * z + c.
- If `modulus of z` > 2 - that is, we're out of the circle - the point is NOT in set
- Otherwise repeat the step.

To prevent that from looping endlessly, limit the max number of iterations.

```
    function is_in_mandelbrot_set($c, $iterations) {
        $z = cpl(0, 0);
        do {
            if(cmod($z) >= 2)
                return false;
            $z = cadd(cmul($z, $z), $c);
        } while($iterations--);
        return true;
    }
```

The rest has nothing to do with math and is quite obvious

```
    function mandelbrot($img, $w, $h) {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0xFF, 0, 0);
        $zoom = 50;
        $iters = 30;

        for($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
            for($y = 0; $y < $h; $y++) {

                // scale our integer points 
                // to be small real numbers around 0

                $px = ($x - $w / 2) / $zoom;
                $py = ($y - $h / 2) / $zoom;

                $c = cpl($px, $py);

                if(is_in_mandelbrot_set($c, $iters))
                    imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $color);
            }
        }

        return $img;
    }

    $w = 200;
    $h = 200;

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng(
        mandelbrot(
            imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h), $w, $h));
```

Result

[image]

Of course, this code is ineffective to the extreme. Its only purpose is to understand the math concept.